# Google Firebase MLKit for Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, firebase-mlkit

Is there Google **Firebase MLKit Vision API** support for Xamarin? I was trying to implement barcode reader using MLKit.

While searching I got an impression that Google is going to stop supporting for Mobile Vision API.

Answer (score 7):

**UDP since 2019:** Packages for Xamarin native

Xamarin.Android -> [Xamarin.Firebase.ML.Vision](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Firebase.ML.Vision/) and

Xamarin.IOS -> [Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.MLKit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.MLKit/).

Answer (score 1):

As of today bindings are not available for Xamarin. They are still working on it, you can expect a release by next month. You can track their progress [here](https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/issues/137) and [here](https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/issues/126)

Answer (score 0):

According to [the official Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/read-barcodes) only Android and iOS are supported at the moment.

However, if your objective is only the barcode-reading functionality, you may find alternatives such as [ZXing.NET](https://blog.xamarin.com/barcode-scanning-made-easy-with-zxing-net-for-xamarin-forms/) or [Scandit](https://docs.scandit.com/5.0/xamarin/index.html)